# ImportError: No module named 'win32con' after installing ConcurrentLogHandler

Tags: python, django, pywin32, easy-install

i'm currently developing in Django under Windows when my colleague installed the ConcurrentLogHandler this error came up.

> ImportError: No module named 'win32con'

it works fine in Ubuntu since his development environment is there, but not on windows.

So, i installed pywin32-220 from (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/)
 to my django app using

> easy_install C:\Users\Downloads\pywin32-220.win32-py3.4.exe

it satisfied the error but its not serving the pages anymore and my cmd is not responding.

Anyone encountered this? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!